# Add custom logo before chapters with Pandoc

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, pandoc

I want to add a custom image near my chapter headings (using the report documentclass).  I want to get something like this:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124083/78981

but with the logo above the chapters, and above the Table of Contents (the positioning is a minor detail).

I am using pandoc, which limits me a bit here - as far as I am aware, I can only add latex headers (.tex files to include at the top) and not edit the chapter code directly.  I have gotten around this limitation by using \rewnewcommand a lot - for example verbatim block set a shaded color & then write the verbatim block.

The chapter code I want to replace looks like this:

```
\chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}
```

And I tried to renew the chapter command to use the TikZ code from the answer above.  Unfortunately that breaks everything.  Even a change like this does not build:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\oldchapter{Hi #1}}
```

I get this error, which goes away when I comment the 2 lines out

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 ...chapter}{\numberline {1}Hi *}{1}{chapter.1}
```

If I could get this working, I think I could get the logos added.  Any suggestions?

Also, I am not tied to the original solution.  I tried the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12158/78981 but for the table of contents the logo is inline with the title - "Contents".

Comment: Macros like `\chapter` are one of the candidates for `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: Furthermore you should use existing solutions like the `titlesec` package or the `memoir` documentclass for these kinds of modifications.

Comment: You should make your `\chapter` and related modifications in a personal `.sty` file and then load that file in some template file (the default one is called something like `default.latex`; see more [here](http://pandoc.org/demo/example9/templates.html)) for the conversion.  I don't really understand what you have been doing, but it sounds wrong to me.